# How to assign the output of uniq command to a variable in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a script to check the status of WAS server to confirm if the server is STARTED or FAILED to start. The server has 2 JVMs. So to check that either of the JVMs are up or not I am using the uniq command.

Lets say JVM1 got FAILED and JVM2 is STARTED, so the below command

```
sh /home/wasprofile/`hostname`/bin/serverStatus.sh -all > /tmp/ServerState

grep "Application Server" /tmp/ServerState|awk '{print $7}'|uniq
```

will show the output as:

```
FAILED
STARTED
```

So now how should i assign this output to two different variables in runtime ??
I mean something like this:

```
a=FAILED
b=STARTED
```

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `uniq` here? Wouldn't you always want to lines of output? With `uniq` if they have the same state you will only get one line of output. Also you don't need `grep` here as `awk` can do that matching also.

Comment: @EtanReisner I am fine using the uniq command when both the JVMs are either up or both are down as I am using that one line output for the if-else condition after that. Only time I am facing issue when one of the JVM is up and other is down... And thanks regarding the suggestion of awk  in place of grep, i have modified the script accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read` with process substitution:

```
read a b < <(awk '/Application Server/ && !seen[$7]++{printf "%s ", $7}' /tmp/ServerState)
```

**PS:** You can avoid `grep` and `uniq` both using awk.

Comment: @anubhava..When I m running this command on shell,I m able to get the expected output..tmp>echo $a FAILED tmp>echo $b STARTED..But when I am using this command in a script I m getting an error as: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `<'  line 3: `read a b < <(awk '/Application Server/ && !seen[$7]++{printf "%s ", $7}' /tmp/ServerState)'...This is the script: #!/bin/bash
read a b < <(awk '/Application Server/ && !seen[$7]++{printf "%s ", $7}' /tmp/ServerState)
echo "The value of a is $a"
echo "The value of b is $b"  Am I doing any mistake while writing the command in the script??

Comment: Yes.. it is a bash shell...                           cwser@asspp2:/tmp> echo $0
-bash                                                               cwser@aspp2:/tmp> awk '/Application Server/ && !seen[$7]++{printf "%s ", $7}' /tmp/ServerState
FAILED STARTED cwser@asspp2:/tmp>

Comment: Its not showing any output....  cwser@asspp2:/tmp> read a b < <(echo "FAILED STARTED ")
cwser@asspp2:/tmp>

Comment: cwser@asspp2:/tmp> awk '/Application Server/ && !seen[$7]++{printf "%s ", $7}' /tmp/ServerState | cat -vte
FAILED STARTED cwser@asspp2:/tmp>

Comment: Without formatted code I cannot see your real output but `read a b < <(awk '/Application Server/ && !seen[$7]++{printf "%s ", $7}' /tmp/ServerState)` should work as it works pretty well for me.